# Sails.js Sockets Working Only Sometimes

Tags: javascript, websocket, sails.js

I'm new to Sails.js (using 0.10.5) and I've been having some bumps with sockets.io.

I have just a user CRUD system with an admin page that monitors real time when user are created, destroyed, logged in or logged out.

I use to instances of chrome: one for the admin and another in incognito mode for the other user.

When I try to create a user and then, in the same page, I log him out and then log him in or try to destroy him, everything works fine. In other words, if I create a user the message verbs 'created', 'updated' and 'destroyed' works amazingly well! even modifying the DOM in real time.

I have one model: User 
And two controllers: SessionController and UserController.

When I login, the 'create' method from the SessionController is called. When I logout, the 'destroy' method of the SessionController is called. Both send publishUpdates to the client.

When I create the user, the UserController sends a publishCreate (and a publishDestroy when destroyed).

However, if I close both pages of the browser (even keeping the server on) and reopen them, the 'updated' messages are not transmitted anymore. Only the 'created' and 'destroyed' verbs still work. (the users are subscribing ok all time).

Any thoughts?

**CODE**

**USER CONTROLLER**

```
subscribe: function(req, res) {
    if (req.isSocket) {
        User.watch(req.socket);
        res.send(200);
    }
}

destroy: function(req, res, next) {
    User.findOne(req.param('id'), function foundUser(err, user) {

        User.destroy(req.param('id'), function userDestroyed(err) {

            User.publishUpdate(user.id, {
                name: user.name,
                action: ' has been destroyed.'
            });

            User.publishDestroy(user.id);
        });
        res.redirect('/user');
    });
},

create: function(req, res, next) {
    var userObj = {
        name: req.param('name'),
    };

    User.create( userObj, function userCreated (err, user) {

        req.session.authenticated = true;
        req.session.User = user;

        user.online = true;

        user.save(function(err, user) {

            user.action = " signed-up and logged-in.";
            User.publishCreate(user);

            res.redirect('/user/show/' + user.id);
        });
    });
}
```

**SESSION CONTROLLER**

```
create: function(req, res, next) {


    User.findOneByEmail(req.param('email'), function foundUser(err, user) {

        req.session.authenticated = true;
        req.session.User = user;

        user.online = true;

        user.save(function(err, user) {

            User.publishUpdate(user.id, {
                loggedIn: true,
                id: user.id,
                name: user.name,
                action: ' has logged in.'
            });

            res.redirect('/user/show/' + user.id);
        });
    });
},

destroy: function(req, res, next) {

    User.findOne(req.session.User.id, function foundUser(err, user) {
        var userId = req.session.User.id;

        User.update(userId, { online: false }, function(err) {

            User.publishUpdate(userId, {
                loggedIn: false,
                id: userId,
                name: user.name,
                action: ' has logged out.'
            });

            req.session.destroy();
            res.redirect('/session/new');
        });
    });
}
```

**APP.JS**

```
io.socket.on('connect', function socketConnected() {

    io.socket.on('user', function (message) {

        switch (message.verb) {
                case 'created':
                    console.log('User ' + message.data.name + message.data.action);
                    break;

                case 'updated':
                    console.log('User ' + message.data.name + message.data.action);
                    break;

                case 'destroyed':
                    console.log('User ' + message.id + ' has been destroyed');
                    break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    });

    socket.get('/user/subscribe');
});
```

**POLICY**

```
  if (req.session.User) {
    return ok();
  } else {
    res.send(403);
  }
```

Comment: Hello, please always provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. In addition, describe what you already tried.

Comment: Sorry, had forgotten... I added some breakpoints before the publishUpdate calls and it always gets in! really can't figure out why isn't working after I reopen the browser...